# Change only vline arrayrulecolor in tables

Tags: tables, color

I tried to change the color of my vline's in a table. I just swapped between `\arrayrulecolor{white}` and `\arrayrulecolor{black}`. Is it possible to only change the color for e.g. the **vlines's** so the **hline's** are not affected of my setting?

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
    %\rowcolors{1}{TUMGray3}{}
    \footnotesize
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c|C{2.45cm}|C{2.3cm}|C{2.1cm}|C{2.15cm}|c}
        \arrayrulecolor{black}
        \hline
        \TabHead Schriftgröße h &\TabHead Höhe der Kleinbuchstaben &\TabHead Abstand zwischen Zeichen &\TabHead Abstand zwischen Zeilen &\TabHead Abstand zwischen Wörtern &\TabHead Linienbreite d \\
        \hline %\TabHead formatiert die Überschriften der ersten Zeile
         \textbf{3,5} & 2,5  & 0,7 & 5 & 2,1 & \textbf{0,35}  \\ %\hline
         \textbf{5} & 3,5  & 1 & 7 & 3 & \textbf{0,5}  \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Schriftgrößen}
    \label{tab:schriftgroessen}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is the code

```
!{\color{green}\vrule}
```

where you want colored verticals to appear

[image]

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX!{\color{green}\vrule}X!{\color{red}\vrule}X!{\color{blue}\vrule}X!{\color{black}\vrule}X}

\hline 
Schriftgröße h & Höhe der Kleinbuchstaben & Abstand zwischen Zeichen & Abstand zwischen Zeilen & Abstand zwischen Wörtern & Linienbreite d \\ 
\hline 
    \end{tabularx}
```

Another example of the same type

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l!{\color{green}\vrule}l}
        \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
        test & test\\\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot @js bibra. This fixed my problem.
May I ask you another question regarding the same issue? Is it also possible, to only have the colored vertical lines in my tablhead?

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{1pt}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X!{\color{white}\vrule}C{2.2cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}C{2.3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}C{3cm}!{\color{white}\vrule}L{3.6cm}}
        \hline
        \TabHead Blattgrößen\newline Reihe A &\TabHead Beschnittene Zeichnung &\TabHead Zeichenfläche &\TabHead Unbeschnittenes Blatt &\TabHead Günstige Rollenbreite\\
        \TabHead & \TabHead Breite \hfill Höhe & \TabHead Breite \hfill Höhe & \TabHead Breite \hfill Höhe & \TabHead  \\
        \hline %\TabHead formatiert die Überschriften der ersten Zeile
        A0 & 1189 \hfill 841 & 1159 \hfill 821 & 1230 \hfill 880 & 900 \hfill  \\ %\hline
        A1 & 841 \hfill 594 & 811 \hfill 574 & 880 \hfill 625 & 900 \hfill 660 \\ %\hline
        A2 & 594 \hfill 420 & 564 \hfill 400 & 625 \hfill 450 & 900 \hfill 660 \\ %\hline
        A3 & 420 \hfill 297 & 390 \hfill 277 & 450 \hfill 330 & 900 \hfill 660 \\ %\hline
        A4 & 210 \hfill 297 & 180 \hfill 277 & 240 \hfill 330 & 660 \hfill \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \label{tab:papierformate}
\end{table}
```

[image: myexample]

Thank u so much for help